# Jekyll + Github Actions + JavaScript runtime issue

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, github-actions, jekyll-theme

I recently decided to start my website with Jekyll.
Things seem straight forward but myself I am not too much of  Gem proficient ;)

For convenience I am using the Jekyll GitHub action ( the official as well as few others I have found on Git ).

I keep getting on the same issue.

I have try to do follow instructions found on multiple sites as well as the recommendation on the error.

I have attached my Gemfile as well as the error

My git repo for this is https://github.com/stiliajohny/stiliajohny.github.io

The Github action runs on ubuntu-latest ( most of the one I tried do run on the same )

**EDIT: ** building it on my local works fine

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "jekyll" , "3.8.7"
gem "bundler"
gem "dev-portfolio-blog"
gem "html-proofer"
gem "execjs"
```

```
️ Building website...
Configuration file: /github/workspace/repo/_config.yml
/usr/local/bundle/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
jekyll 3.8.7 | Error:  Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `gem "therubyracer"` to the Gemfile. [This](https://github.com/rubyjs/therubyracer) embeds the V8 JavaScript interpreter into Ruby.

Comment: unfortunately it is still the same issue .. which I find it a bit odd 

This is the full log if you could make sense of it :/ 

https://pastebin.com/Scx2GmPU

Comment: I've looked through that file and think the error comes down to [this](https://github.com/digitalsparky/jekyll-minifier/blob/faab5fb1bce8b728080b4fe3bc42adba93594c44/lib/jekyll-minifier.rb#L44) line. I don't know ruby, so don't know what that line does (I'm probably wrongly assuming .map is the same as in JavaScript.) The only thing I can really suggest is to create an issue there in the hopes someone with more experience will see it.

Comment: Another thing is that I've tried to clone your repo locally but I cannot get all of the packages to install correctly. I don't know if its conflicting with stuff I already have or if it dislikes the stuff in the gemfile. The log looks like everything is working through actions,  so its probably something I've screwed up.